# C# Return Component View in Different Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have a view that needs to load different component vieww dynamically based on component view name. I am using a function in C# to achieve this:

```
public ViewComponentResult GetComponentView(string componentName, int id)
{
   return ViewComponent(componentName, new { id = id });
}
```

This is in a controller CT40. So the file structure is:

/Controllers/CT40/CT40Controller

/Views/CT40/Components/Maintenance/Default.cshtml
/Views/CT40/Components/Maintenance/MaintenanceViewComponents.cs

Inside MaintenanceViewComponents.cs I have:

```
[ViewComponent(Name = "Maintenance")]
```

It works find when I call the GetComponentView function with "Maintenance" as the component name.

But I want to move the GetComponentView function to the HomeController. When I do this, it returns

"System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Maintenance/Default'"

I have tried every path I can think of, same thing:

/CT04000/Maintenance

/CT04000/Components/Maintenance

/CT04000/Components/Maintenance/Default.cshtml

Views/CT04000/Components/Maintenance/Default.cshtml

Same error every time.

Any idea what path I need to put in to get Homecontroller to look in:
/Views/CT40/Components/Maintenance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking at the problem in the wrong place.

I was trying to put the path to the view in componentName here:

```
public ViewComponentResult GetComponentView(string componentName, int id)
{
   return ViewComponent(**componentName**, new { id = id });
}
```

But the path needed to go in statement

```
return View(path, model);
```

in the file MaintenanceViewComponents.cs.

I added the path "~/Views/CT04000/Components/Maintenance/Default.cshtml" and worked liked charm.